# Convert SQL select statement to Linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, sql-to-linq-conversion

How can I convert the following SQL select statement to Linq?

```
SELECT u.Name FROM User u AS DDC
INNER JOIN Country c ON c.UserId = u.UserId
INNER JOIN (
     SELECT AddressId,
            Address, 
            PC, 
        FROM AddressTbl a
    WHERE a.CountryId = 1
) AS Addresses ON Addresses.AddressId= u.AddressId

WHERE 

u.UserIs = @UserId AND
Addresses.AddressId= @AddressId
```

Any good reading references?

Comment: This is a question that is relevant to you but will never be of interest to anyone else. It would be better to ask about the T-SQL structures that give you trouble. eg. the subquery join.

Comment: thanks. I made the sql more simple..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from u in Users join 
     c in Country on  c.UserId equals u.UserId
     join a in Address on a.AddressId equals u.AddressId     
where a.CountryId == 1
select u.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out
http://www.sqltolinq.com/